# Поле и/или переменная? Вот в чем вопрос

Tags: java, ооп, классы, переменные

По ходу моего обучения языка Java термин "поле" не дает мне покоя. Я ни в книгах, ни в сети не нашел понятного объяснения этого явления. Кто-то говорит, что "поле" - это "переменная", просто название другое (для примера: объект и экземпляр). В других источниках - это разные вещи.

Так вот, **что такое "поле"?** Дополнил примером. Он верный?

```
class MyClass{

int weigth = 50; //---поле
int height = 100; //---поле 
String str; //---поле

int myMethod(){
    
    int a; //---локальная переменная (НЕ поле)
    int b; //---локальная переменная (НЕ поле)
    str = "Это строка"; //---полю присваивается значение

    ...
}}
```

Comment: Поле - это скорее не просто переменная, а переменная типа инстанса, то есть то, что Вы в классе объявляете. Например, public class A {private String str;}. Так вот str - это поле aka. field. Есть еще локальные переменные и параметры, но это уже не филды.

Comment: поле - это то на что вы пишите гетеры и сетеры, а переменная это то, что внутри функции вы объявляете

Comment: Это названия из мира ООП, которые указывают на местоположение. Классы состоят из полей и методов. При этом поля это переменные класса, а методы это функции класса. Если вы слышите слово "поле", то сразу становится понятно, что переменная принадлежит классу и может быть доступна только из экземпляра класса или самого класса в случае если поле статическое.

Comment: А вообще это из-за того, что ООП по сути парадигма, которая представляет все объекты окружающего мира в виде свойств(вес, длина, кол-во ног и т.д.) и действий которые можно совершать с ним(бежать, кидать, кричать, вычислять). Объекты названы классами, их свойства названы полями, а совершаемые действия с ними методами. Когда переносим эту абстракцию на сам язык программирования, то для полей используем переменные, а для методов функции.

Comment: То есть "поле" - это, все таки, переменная? Как я понял "поле" это та переменная, что указывается сразу же после объявления класса и может быть использована абсолютно всеми методами определенными в этом классе. Верно?

Comment: Все верно, грубо говоря это та переменная, что указывается сразу после объявления класса. Дальше просто для информации, если вы не слышали про модификаторы public и static, то потом встретите, сейчас вы используете private - видна только методам внутри класса. 1) Поле не обязательно объявлять сразу, можно их раскидать по всему телу класса, это не будет ошибкой. 2) Можно ее объявить публичной, тогда к ней можно обратиться извне: MyClass instance = new MyClass(); instance.**SomeField** = 10; 3) Она может быть статичной, тогда доступна из самого класса MyClass.**SomeField** = 10.

Comment: @AlexKrass Спасибо) Вы помогли мне понять что к чему)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Понятие "поле" отнюдь не является чем-то новым в Java. Оно скорее переехало из других языков, существовавших задолго до Java. Так для меня "поле" всегда ассоциировалось с названием колонки в таблице. В Java объекты имеют определенный [тип, который может быть классом, интерфейсом, или перечисляемым типом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/field.html). Внутри этих объектов мы можем определять переменные, которые определяют состояние этих объектов. И наподобие с таблицами, которые имею названия полей для каждой записи, мы имеем названия переменных для каждого объекта класса.

Не исключено, что внутри класса вы можете создавать другие переменные, например *локальные* переменные, или переменные *параметры*, которые видны в пределах блока или метода и тем самым не могут повлиять на состояние объекта. Такие переменные *не являются* полями. Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Понятие "поле" также имеет широкий спектр значений принятых в информатике и означает место, где находятся [*данные*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_(%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо! Информация по ссылкам расширяет мое понимание этих терминов.

Answer (score -1):

На английском языке 2 разных терминов:

- **field** - для атрибута (переменной) в классе,
- **array** - для агрегатной переменной (переменной с многими значениями, доступными через индекс).

Оба эти термины переводятся как **поле**.

И так ваш пример может быть верным или нет - но в его контексте можно его считать верным.